# update iOS app remotely without review process

Tags: ios

What are the thing we can add it to remote server that on further after app is on app store if there is any changes in app it does not require to follow the whole submission and review process ?

Please give your suggestion to make app maximum updatable without review process.

Comment: Content => Text, graphics etc.. But no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download data, which would include new graphical elements.

The guidelines say, *"Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected"*.  However, apps that use HTML and Javascript for some of their logic are typically able to replace those.

Perhaps you would get better answers by starting with a list of the things you'd like to be able to change and see if there are ways to accomplish them.